# How can I convert this SQL Server stored procedure to work in Snowflake

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [state].[AddUpdateDatabaseExtractStatus]
    @databaseId         INT,
    @databaseLoadId     INT,
    @dataFactoryRunId   CHAR(36),
    @phase              VARCHAR(30),
    @startTimeUtc       DATETIME2(7),
    @endTimeUtc         DATETIME2(7),
    @loadGroup          INT = 1,
    @statusId           INT = 1,
    @returnResult       BIT = 1
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @lv_databaseLoadId INT;

IF @lv_databaseLoadId IS NULL
BEGIN
    -- Upsert the row
    MERGE [state].[DatabaseExtract] AS [OE]
    USING (
        VALUES (
            @databaseId,
            @DatabaseLoadId,
            @phase,
            @dataFactoryRunId,
            @startTimeUtc,
            @endTimeUtc,
            @loadGroup,
            @statusId
        )
    ) AS [NEW] (
        [DatabaseId]
        ,[DatabaseLoadId]
        ,[Phase]
        ,[DataFactoryRunId]
        ,[StartTimeUtc]
        ,[EndTimeUtc]
        ,[LoadGroup]
        ,[StatusId]
    )
    ON [OE].[DatabaseId] = [NEW].[DatabaseId] AND [OE].[DatabaseLoadId] = [NEW].[DatabaseLoadId]
    -- AND [OE].[DataFactoryRunId] = [NEW].[DataFactoryRunId]
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE SET
          [StatusId] = [NEW].[StatusId],
          [Phase] = [NEW].[Phase],
          [EndTimeUtc] = [NEW].[EndTimeUtc]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
    -- Add defense again out of band runs causing issues - simply skip logging if the data is not present.
        AND @StartTimeUTC IS NOT NULL AND @loadGroup IS NOT NULL AND @Phase IS NOT NULL and @dataFactoryRunId IS NOT NULL AND @statusId IS NOT NULL
        THEN
        INSERT
        (
            [DatabaseId]
            ,[LoadGroup]
            ,[StatusId]
            ,[Phase]
            ,[DataFactoryRunId]
            ,[StartTimeUtc]
            ,[EndTimeUtc]
        ) VALUES (
            [NEW].[DatabaseId]
            ,[NEW].[LoadGroup]
            ,[NEW].[StatusId]
            ,[NEW].[Phase]
            ,[NEW].[DataFactoryRunId]
            ,[NEW].[StartTimeUtc]
            ,[NEW].[EndTimeUtc]
        )
    ;

    IF @returnResult = 1
        SELECT
            DE.[DatabaseLoadId],
            [OperatorName],
            [ServerName],
            [DatabaseName],
            [SourceSystemName],
            [KeyVaultSecretName],
            --[BatchProcess],
            [DNACoreTechSupportEmail]
        FROM (
            SELECT
                MAX([DatabaseLoadId]) AS DatabaseLoadId,
                DatabaseId
            FROM [state].[DatabaseExtract]
            WHERE [DataFactoryRunId] = @dataFactoryRunId AND DatabaseId = @databaseId
            GROUP BY DatabaseId
        ) DE
        INNER JOIN [state_config].[DatabaseList] DL ON DL.[DatabaseId] = DE.[DatabaseId]
END

if ((@@trancount) > 0)
COMMIT TRANSACTION -- Safe for other loads to lookup IDs now

END
GO
```

I'm having trouble converting this to a stored procedure in snowflake. this works in SQL Server, but snowflake doesn't seem to like the table name after `FROM` statement. I looked around and cant seem to find anything relating to this.

Comment: so what have you tried?, what error's do you get?, do you understand the difference in the SQL syntax's and thus the basic translations you will have to do?

Comment: Those are 2 different databases so obviously the SP implementation is going to be different. Focus more on what the code does and less on converting the syntax. Once you figure out the logic, include some sample data, expected output and some explanation for said output